# How to run express app in hosting? I have a 503 error on my web

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to deploy my express app to a2 hosting, which has setup node js app.
This is my current settings:
[image]

I upload my file into the root directory, just by zipping myfiles and extract them there, and making a .env file. I also deleted their app.js file. But when i tried to access my app on the web, it gives me a 503 service unavailable.
This is my index.js file

```
const     express = require('express'),
            mysql = require('mysql'),
             cors = require('cors'),
      bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
      fileUpload  = require('express-fileupload'),
      mysqlCONFIG = require('./config/mysql-db').mysqlCONFIG

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const db = mysql.createConnection(mysqlCONFIG)

db.connect((err) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Fail to make a connection.')
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to MYSQL Database');
  }
})

const app = express()
app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser())

require('./routes/products-routes')(app, db);

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

Is this a problem on my code or the app is taking too much memory? Am i missing something? Do i need the httaccess file? or do i need to create a http request. Somebody please help.

Comment: i already run npm install from their cpanel node js setup

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god it turns out one of the npm package which was mkdir is causing the problems. I need to use fssync next time.